# Passing variables to JS from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pymongo

I want to know if it is possible, to pass variables from MongoDB to JavaScript. I have an assignment where I would like to create a group of collections of the following form: coll + X, where x is the number (key), which will be passed from Mongo. The snippet below shows what I'm trying to achieve.

```
reduceInit = Code(
    "function(KEY, values) {"
        "var name = 'coll' + KEY;"
        "db.name.insert({a : 1});"
    "return {something: []};"
    "}"
)
```

I have seen the db.eval function, but I don't know how it could be used in this case.

**EDIT**:

```
"var word = key;"
"db.coll[word].insert({something : 1});"
```

So i found out I can create collections using the above two lines of code. The problem is, this produces the name of the form: **coll.X** The problem now is, how to get rid of the dot in the name.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are not you not doing this from client side code instead of trying to break your programming with a single threaded engine and locking with eval? I am also not sure what you mean by: "to pass variables from MongoDB to JavaScript" What you are doing there is actually using JS to insert something into MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

In python, it's as simple as:

```py
db['coll' +  str(key)].insert({'something': 1})
```

But are you sure you want to go with all these collections?  Would be much easier to use a single collection with `key` as an indexed field.